# Object to bone parenting: How to disassociate while editing armature?

Tags: armature, transforms, parent

I have set up an armature with several objects parented to various bones (it’s LEGOs, so no need for individual deformation). However, editing the armature now makes parented objects move. That is, the objects’ offset from any particular bone tail does not change when moving said tail editorially. Can I disable this somewhere? Does this have to do with inverse parenting?

Also, even setting the origin of the armature to a new location causes similar motion that I do not understand.

Comment: hello could you please show some screenshots?

Comment: @moonboots Yes, though it might take me awhile to get them. Different time zone

Comment: If you've parented the object to the bone with a simple parent to > Bone, and if you move the bone's tail, it will move the object, so maybe you need to deparent the object, edit the bone then reparent?

Comment: @moonboots That works, but it’s like 15 objects on one bone.

Comment: so maybe you should instead join all the objects and parent With Empty Groups?

Comment: @moonboots I could do that, but I’m still trying to maintain flexibility in the future. Maybe that’s just a limitation of the system.